# JAX-RS how to use ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, jax-rs, java-ee-7

I've read through https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html about how implementing customized exception handlers, which will be discovered during scanning.

I'm not very familiar with the `Provider` mechanism, I'm wondering where should I declare the customized ExceptionMapper: should I declare a general global one or one each in every JAX RS resource? If global one, what should I do if a few JAX RS want to use some specific exception mapper while most JAXRS resources are ok with the global general one? What's the mechanism the scanning discover potential Providers?

Comment: ExceptionMappers are chosen by the Exception class hierarchy. The mapper declared with the nearest exception class to the exception being thrown, will be the one used. For example if you have a mapper for `Throwable` and one for `WebApplicationException`, if a `NotFoundException` is thrown, the latter will be used. If an `IllegalStateException` is thrown, the former will be used. To discover mappers, use the `@Provider` annotation on top of the mapper class. The scanning mechanism will pick up the mapper. If you don't have scanning enabled, you need to manually register the mapper.